# Hide partial background repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Consider these simple CSS rules:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upjkd/11/)

```css
div#container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 260px;
    background-image: url('Image.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}​
```

The problem is that I only want full images. If there is not enough space for another duplicate, it should NOT be shown.

I've never heard that CSS provides a rule for it. So how can I achieve it in JavaScript (jQuery already included)?

Comment: You can't, at least not as a background image, and without resizing the element.

Comment: So the only solution I have is to determine the nearest fitting width for the container via JavaScript. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the way to go, or you could insert the images in the HTML and calculate how many will fit etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with current CSS rules. You can repeat once, or repeat forever. The alternative is to shrink the size of the containing element to fit the nearest repeating point in either CSS (if you know the width before page load) or JS (if you don't).

Here's the latter implentation using jQuery:

```
var $container = $("#container");
var bgImg = extractUrl($container.css("background-image"));
var $img = $("<img />", { "src" : bgImg }).hide().appendTo("body");

$container.width(nearest($("#container").width(), $img.width()));
$img.remove();

function extractUrl(input) {
    // remove quotes and wrapping url()
    return input.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
}

function nearest(n, v) {
    n = n / v;
    n = Math.floor(n) * v;
    return n;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/upjkd/6/)

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I wanted!

Comment: Hmm I've just encountered a problem with IE 10 which seams to simply cut my image at the right side :( The width is completely divisible by the image width.

Answer (score 2):

### This will work for percentage widths and auto adjusts on sreen resize.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    var img = $('<img/>');
    img.attr('src', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Fussball.jpg').load(function () {
        var height = this.height;
        var width = this.width;
        var divWidth = $('#containerwrap').width();
        var extra = divWidth % width;
        $('div#container').width(divWidth - extra);

    });
});
```

---

```
div#container {
    width: 670px;
    height: 260px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Fussball.jpg') left center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#containerwrap{
    width:100%;
    height: 260px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

---

```
<div id="containerwrap">
  <div id="container">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/upjkd/14/show

Answer (score 0):

As the width is fixed by the server, and the server knows the size of the image - why not construct the image to be correct and forget the repeat, or make the width the appropriate size so it will fit whole number of images?

Comment: The width is not fixed! It is actually 60% of the browser's width. The values in the example were only for demonstration purpose.

Comment: So why not change the width value in the above example so people are able to infer what you require?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question. But Rory has already solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/upjkd/10/

```
var img=document.createElement('img');
img.src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Fussball.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(img);
var con=document.getElementById('container'),
    numImages=Math.round(con.clientWidth/img.clientWidth);
con.style.backgroundSize=con.clientWidth/numImages+'px';
document.body.removeChild(img);
```

You can use `Math.round(con.clientWidth/img.clientWidth)` to determine the number of repetitions of the image, and then use `con.style.backgroundSize=con.clientWidth/numImages+'px'` to be sure that the number of images is an integrer (only full images).